# How does Sequelize destroy function work?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've been trying to delete a user in a MySql database using Sequelize ORM but it's not deleting.

1. without paranoid, here's the query generate:

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `active`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?
```

2. with paranoid set to true, here's the query generate:

```
 UPDATE `Users` SET `active`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE (`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `id` = ?)
```

digging around the internet i found out that the the query is supposed to take this form `UPDATE "posts" SET "deletedAt"=[timestamp] WHERE "deletedAt" IS NULL AND "id" = 1` accounding to this [Documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/paranoid.html).

Here's my model:

```
'use strict';
const sequelizePaginate = require('sequelize-paginate')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    photo: DataTypes.STRING,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    role: DataTypes.STRING,
    verifyEmailAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    referralCode: DataTypes.STRING,
    active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    referrer: DataTypes.STRING,
    rememberToken: DataTypes.STRING
    
  }, { instanceMethods: {
    comparePasswords: (password, prevPassword,callback) => {
      bcrypt.compare(password, prevPassword, (error, isMatch) => {
          if(error) {
              return callback(error);
          }
  
          return callback(null, isMatch);
      });
  }
},
hooks: {
    beforeValidate: (user) => {
      if(user.changed('password')) {
          return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(function(password) {
              user.password = password;
          });
      }
  }
}});
  User.associate = (models) => {
    // associations can be defined here
    models.User.hasMany(models.Booking)
    models.User.hasMany(models.DriversLocation)
    models.User.hasMany(models.DriverReview)
    models.User.hasMany(models.Payment)
  };
  sequelizePaginate.paginate(User)
  return User;
};
```

And also my query snippet:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const models = require('../models')

deleteAdmin: (req, res) => {
            const result = validationResult(req);
            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(422).json({ success: false, message: 'input validation failure',
                code: 422, properties:{ userId : req.params.userId}, error: result.array()  });
            
            }
            models.User.destroy({
                where: {
                  id: req.params.userId
                }
              })
            .then((data) => {
                return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "success",
                code: 200, properties:{params: {userId: req.params.userId }}, 
                data: {content: data}});
            }).catch((error) => {
                return res.status(520).json({ success: false, message: "unknown error",
                code: 520, properties:{params: {userId: req.params.userId }}, 
                data: { error: error}  });
            })
        }
```

**Is there something am doing wrong here?**

**Thank you for your help in advance**

Answer (score 0):

`destroy` usage seems fine to me. Please verify your `User` model import & `req params` values.

Also, there is no `id` field defined in schema definition. How is `id` being saved in DB record ?

Comment: The userId here refers to id which is automatically generated by the sequelize

Comment: Again, the destroy method is referencing active column(which is of type Boolean) as can be shown from the generated query whereas the deletedAt column is of type datetime which is auto-generated by sequelize

Comment: I have worked with _sequalize & Mysql_ and this method generates a **DELETE** query when `paranoid` is not set. 

However, if you have `paranoid` set then it works as _soft-delete_ & only updates _deletedAt_ (or any name you choose) field's timestamp.

Comment: Could you test it for a new model without setting `paranoid` field ?

Comment: I've finally seen the error after spending days digging around. In my routes file i mistakely called: ```router.get('/admin/deleteAdmin/:userId', param('userId').notEmpty().isNumeric(), AdminManager.deactivateAdmin)``` instead of  ```router.get('/admin/deleteAdmin/:userId', param('userId').notEmpty().isNumeric(), AdminManager.deleteAdmin)```. that was the problem. I guess i was really drained out after working for several hours and that error went and unnoticed which brought so much pain. thank you so much